# Parse string with multiple fields of a structure in C

Tags: c, string, file

Suppose I have a text file with a content similar to the following:

```
JohnWatsonAustralia25
```

And I have a structure like this:

```
struct Employee {
    char name[16];
    char last_name[16];
    char country[16];
    char age[16];
};
```

Is there any way to read all four strings in one instruction with *fscanf?* So that they are stored like this:

```
name = "John"
last_name = "Watson"
country = "Australia"
age = 25
```

For example, something like the following code but that separates the strings correctly (obviously that doesn't work as I want it to):

```
fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%s", name, last_name, country, age);
```

EDIT 1: The start of each text field is always a capital letter, there are no "McMahon" type fields with two capital letters. The first digit denotes the start of the age field and there are no spaces or any kind of delimiter character, all fields are joined as in the first example I put.

EDIT 2: All fields are at least two characters long and are not expected to exceed the maximum space of fifteen characters.

Comment: You have not fully specified the format of the text file. Is the start of a new text field always a capital letter, and is a capital letter always the start of a new text field? You will never have a name like “McMahon”? Or “von Ardenne”? Does the first digit always denote the start of the age field? Can there be any spaces between fields? In a field?

Comment: Are all names more than one character? Why is `age` an array of `char` instead of an integer type?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry, I forgot that detail. I already edited my question, I hope I was clear this time. All fields are of two or more characters (the first one is always a capital letter) and the reason I used char[] instead of int is because I don't plan to use that data for any calculations, I just need to store the information although I am not sure if it is easier to handle it as an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the rule, if any, is for how the string is to be separated into fields.  If the first three fields are to be recognized as an initial capital Latin letter followed by between one and fourteen lowercase Latin letters, and the last field is to be recognized as a sequence of up to 15 decimal digits, then you could use variations on this:

```
struct employee e;

int num_fields = fscanf(file,
       " %1[A-Z]%14[a-z]%1[A-Z]%14[a-z]%1[A-Z]%14[a-z]%15[0-9]",
       e.name, e.name + 1, e.last_name, e.last_name + 1, e.country, e.country + 1,
       e.age);

if (num_fields != 6) {
    // handle input error
}
```

Note that that will skip leading whitespace (explicitly, as `%s` would do implicitly), but it will not allow whitespace between the fields.  It also assumes that you want each field of the structure to receive a null-terminated string, so that one character must be reserved for a terminator in all cases.

But really, don't do that.  Surely you see how hard it is to read or understand.  It would be better to be a bit more verbose by reading the whole input into a string and then parsing it from there.

Comment: yes, @EricPostpischil, I just saw that.  update coming...

Comment: That is correct, Eric, it will not handle single-character names.  That is already stipulated in the description of the format it assumes.

Comment: (An option for using the structure as shown is that it contains names of up to 16 characters in length, with a null character marking the end of names shorter than 16 characters. We cannot know the specification just from the structure definition.)

Comment: That is true, Eric.  Then one might want a variation on the code presented, as this answer already says might be needed.

Comment: Apart from the other hurdles... Some people have 'hyphenated surnames'... Looking at you, "Winnie Madikizela-Mandela"... And "NewZealand" would present yet another challenge...

Comment: Yes, @Fe2O3.  That would not be accommodated by the specific code presented (nor by the source format I have specified), but it could be handled by variations on those.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, that's just what I needed. I forgot to specify formatting details when I posted the question but I already edited it.

Comment: @DiegoFC Having read your edits to the OP, you've arbitrarily excluded MANY possibilities that could arise: "Sharkira", "Thor", "Carl Phillip Emmanuel Bach", "New { Zealand | Calendonia | ... }", "USA"... Mr Bollinger answered best: "There's no simple way to use Regex to parse such a file [without arbitrary limits on its content]"